# Drools Guvnor Tomcat 7 validateJarFile - jar not loaded

Tags: tomcat7, drools, drools-guvnor

Using drools-guvnor (5.5.0) 
When starting Tomcat the catalina.yyyy-MM-dd.log file shows this warning.

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/.../tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/webapps/drools-guvnor/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

When I moved the offending jar file to /tmp directory, shutdown and restarted Tomcat, the message did not appear in the log. Guvnor **seems** to be working.

- Is jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar required under Tomcat7?
- What is the purpose of the this jar?
- What is best practice to deal with the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just exclude the .jar from the .war. Tomcat already provides the Servlet apis, so there is no need to include them in Guvnor.

Hope it helps,